# Using click events with listbox to display image in python tkinter

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox, bind

I am attempting to create a click event using listbox to display an image file in a top level window when selecting items from the listbox. When executing the code the program runs without error. However, when I select an item from the listbox I receive the error

> "Exception in Tkinter callback Traceback (most recent call last):
> File
> "C:\Users\steve\AppData\Local\Programs\Python\Python39\lib\tkinter_*init*_.py",
> line 1884, in **call**
> return self.func(*args) TypeError: listboxevent() takes 1 positional argument but 2 were given".

Correct me if I am wrong but I don't believe I am passing any positional arguments to the listboxevent() method. Any insight here would be appreciated.

```
from tkinter import *
import tkinter as tk

class Image_viewer:
    
    def __init__(self, win):
        self.root = win
        self.root.title('Root Window')
        self.root.geometry('200x150+600+200')
        
        self.lblHeading = tk.Label(self.root,
                                   text = 'Root Window',
                                   font = ('Times New Roman', 14),
                                   bg = 'White')
        self.lblHeading.pack(side = tk.TOP)
        self.lblHeading.focus()
        
        self.btnView = tk.Button(self.root, text = 'Image Viewer', command = self.view)
        self.btnView.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.9, anchor = tk.SE)
        self.btnClose = tk.Button(self.root, text = 'Close', command = self.close)
        self.btnClose.place(relx = 0.8, rely = 0.9, anchor = tk.SE)

   #function for inserting image based off selection
    def listboxinsert(self):
        self.imgas = tk.PhotoImage(file = '../raw/as.png')
        self.imggr = tk.PhotoImage(file = '../raw/gr.png')
        cs = self.Lb.curselection()
        
        if self.Lb.get(cs) == 0:
                #creates textbox to insert image into 
                self.mytext = tk.Text(self.top)
                self.mytext.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.80, height=150, width=200, anchor = tk.CENTER)
                #inserts image into textbox
                self.mytext.image_create(tk.END, image = self.imgas) 
        elif self.Lb.get(cs) == 1:
                #creates textbox to insert image into  
                self.mytext = tk.Text(self.top)
                self.mytext.place(relx = 0.5, rely = 0.80, height=150, width=200, anchor = tk.CENTER)
                #inserts image into textbox
                self.mytext.image_create(tk.END, image = self.imggr)
    def view(self):
        #creating top level
        self.top = Toplevel()
        self.top.title('Top Level')
        self.top.geometry('500x500')
        #Quit Button
        self.btnClose2 = Button(self.top, text="Quit", command= self.top.destroy)
        self.btnClose2.place(relx = 0.9, rely = 0.1, anchor = tk.SE)
        #initializing listbox
        self.Lb = Listbox(self.top, height=6) 
        self.Lb.place(relx = 0.3, rely = 0.3, anchor = tk.SE)
        #binding event to listbox selection
        self.Lb.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', self.listboxinsert)

        # Inserting items in Listbox 
        self.Lb.insert(0, 'as') 
        self.Lb.insert(1, 'gr')
   
    def close(self):
        self.root.destroy()
      
def main():
    root = tk.Tk()
    Image_viewer(root)
    root.mainloop()
    
if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: `self.Lb.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', self.listboxevent)` ->   `self.Lb.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', self.listboxinsert)` and `def listboxinsert(self):` -> `def listboxinsert(self, event):`

Comment: My apologies the "self.Lb.bind('<<ListboxSelect>>', self.listboxevent)" was a typo I made when editing the post. I have modified def listboxinsert(self): to def listboxinsert(self, event): like you suggested and I am no longer receiving the positional arguments error but the image is still not displayed in the top level window.

Comment: `if self.Lb.get(cs) == 0`  -> `if cs[0]==0` similarly `elif self.Lb.get(cs) == 1:` -> `elif cs[0]==1` or just change `cs = self.Lb.curselection()` - > `cs = self.Lb.curselection()[0]` this way u don't need `cs[0]==0` instead just `cs == 0` will do.

Comment: Worked like a charm. Greatly appreciated!